# Happens before and program order in Java Memory Model

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model

I have some question regarding program order and how it affects reorderings in the JMM.

In the Java Memory Model, program order (*po*) is defined as the total order of actions in each thread in a program. According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-110), this induces happens-before (*hb*) edges:

> If `x` and `y` are actions of the same thread and `x` comes before `y` in
> program order, then *hb(x, y)* (i.e. `x` happens-before `y`).

So for a simple program P:

```
  initially, x = y = 0
     T1     |     T2
 -----------|-----------
  1. r1 = x | 3. r2 = y  
  2. y = 1  | 4. x = r2
```

I think *po(1, 2)* and *po(3, 4)*. Thus, *hb(1, 2)* and *hb(3, 4)*.

Now suppose I wanted to reorder some of these statements, giving me P':

```
  initially, x = y = 0
     T1     |     T2
 -----------|-----------
  2. y = 1  | 3. r2 = y  
  1. r1 = x | 4. x = r2
```

According to [this paper](http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf), we can reorder any two adjacent statements (e.g. 1 and 2), provided that the reordering doesn't eliminate any transitive happens-before edges in any valid execution. However, since *hb* is defined (partially) by *po*, and *po* is a total order over a thread's actions, it seems to me that it would be impossible to reorder any two statements without violating *hb*, thus *P'* is not a legal transformation.

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding of *po* and *hb* correct, and have I correctly defined *po* and *hb* with respect to the above program *P*?
2. Where is my understanding about reordering with regards to *hb* failing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing this part of the JLS:

> It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.

In your case, since 1 and 2 are unrelated, they can be flipped. Now if 2 had been `y = r1`, then 1 must happen before 2 for the right result.

---

The real problem occurs with multi-processor execution. Without any happen-before boundaries, T2 may observe 2 happening before 1, regardless of execution order.

This is because of CPU caching. Let's say T1 executed 1 and 2, in any order. Since no happen-before boundary exist, these actions are still in CPU cache, and depending on other needs, the part of the cache containing the result of 2 may be flushed before the part of the cache that contains the result of 1.

If T2 executes between those two cache flush events, it'll observe 2 has happened and 1 hasn't, i.e. 2 happened before 1, as far as T2 knows.

If this is not allowed, then T1 must establish a happens-before boundary between 1 and 2.

In Java there are various ways of doing that. The old style would be to put 1 and 2 into separate `synchronized` blocks, because the start and end of a `synchronized` block is a happens-before boundary, i.e. any action before the block happens before actions inside the block, and any action inside the block happens before actions coming after the block.

Comment: Based on that part of the JLS you linked, my understanding is now this: we have a program *P*, with a program order *po* and happens-before order *hb*. If we want to transform into *P'*, we're not trying to find *P'* such that *P'* preserves *po* and *hb* - we're finding a whole new *po'* and *hb'* for *P'* that produces results consistent with the originals? That is, the orders of *P* and *P'* can be completely different, provided they exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: @Kumalh that is correct, it's also called a _perceivable_ outcome of the program. This answer is 100% correct, to me. 1+

Answer (score 1):

What you have described as P', is in fact not a different program, but an execution trace of the same program P. It could be a different program, but then it would have different *po*, and therefore different *hb*.

Happens-before relation restricts statement reordering with regards to their observable effect, not their execution order. Action *1* happens-before *2*, but they don't observe each other's result, so they are allowed to be reordered.
*hb* guarantees that you will observe that two actions were executed in-order, but only from synchronized context (i.e. from other actions forming *hb* with *1* and *2*). You may think of *1* and *2* saying: *Let's swap. No one's watching!*.

Here is a good example from JLS that reflects happens-before idea quite well:

> For example, the write of a default value to every field of an object constructed by a thread need not happen before the beginning of that thread, as long as no read ever observes that fact

In practice, it is rarely possible to order default-value writes of all objects constructed by a thread before it starts, even though they form *synchronized-with* edge with every action in that thread. A starting thread may not know what, and how many objects it will construct in run time. But once you have a reference to an object, you will observe that default value writes have already happened. Ordering default writes of an object not yet constructed (or known to be constructed) often cannot be reflected in execution, but it still does not violate *happens-before* relation, because it is all about observable effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think a key issue is with your construction `P'`. It implies that the way re-ordering works is that re-ordering is global - the entire program is re-ordered in single way (on each execution) which obeys the memory model. Then you are trying to reason about this `P'` and find out that no interesting re-orderings are possible!

What actually occurs is that there is no particular global order for statements not related by a *hb* relationship, so different threads can see different apparent orders on the same execution. In your example, there are no edges between {1,2} and {3,4} statements in one set can see those in the other set in any order. For example, it is possible that `T2` observes `2` before `1`, but that then `T3`, which is identical to `T2` (with its own private variables), observes the opposite! So there is no single reordering P' - each thread may observe their own reorderings, as long as they are consistent with the JMM rules.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some question regarding program order and how it affects reorderings in the JMM.

*Strictly* speaking about program order: it simply can't affect anything, at least not in a perceivable way. Program order is *not* something that can be "broken"; it exists only so that a general model about a program starts to take shape.

In other words, program order is only needed so that we know how the original source code looked like. It is also important to note such a statement:

> Among all the inter-thread actions performed by each thread t, the program order of t is a total order that reflects the order in which these actions **would be performed**

Not *will* be performed, but *would*. So, `po` does not say the order in which actions will happen, it only says the order in the original source code.

Yes, `po` will also bring `hb`, but `A happens-before B` does *not* mean `A actually happening before B`. A great article [here](https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/) about this, and the most important part here:

> (2) still behaves the same as it would have even if the effects of (1) had been visible, which is effectively the same as (1)’s effects being visible.

---

Since your variables `x` and `y` are plain variable and there is no dependency between `(1)` and `(2)`, that reordering is legal. The *perceivable* outcome for `(1)` and `(2)` for `T1` is the same, no matter the order in which `(1)` and `(2)` get executed; and because `x` and `y` are plain variables, it is allowed for those actions to be reordered.